# How to copy records from one table to another SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble inserting records from another table, hope you can help me

Origin table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inpe_Origen]
(
    [Pri_Apellido] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Seg_Apellido] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Nombres] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Dni] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Fec_Ing_Sis] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Fec_Ing_Pen] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Fec_Egr_Pen] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Cod_Penal_Ori] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Des_Penal_Ori] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Cod_Penal_Des] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Des_Penal_Des] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Mot_Movimiento] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Aut_Ordena] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Num_Expdiente] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Del_Especifico] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Sit_Juridica] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Nom_Asociados] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Mpfn_Id] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Inpe_Id] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Destination table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inpe_Destino]
(
    [NombreCompleto] [varchar](555) NULL,
    [Dni] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Fec_Ing_Sis] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Fec_Ing_Pen] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Fec_Egr_Pen] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Cod_Penal_Ori] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Des_Penal_Ori] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Cod_Penal_Des] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Des_Penal_Des] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Mot_Movimiento] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Aut_Ordena] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Num_Expdiente] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Del_Especifico] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Sit_Juridica] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Nom_Asociados] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Mpfn_Id] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Inpe_Id] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Inpe_Destino(
NombreCompleto
,Dni
,Fec_Ing_Sis
,Fec_Ing_Pen
,Fec_Egr_Pen
,Cod_Penal_Ori
,Des_Penal_Ori
,Cod_Penal_Des
,Des_Penal_Des
,Mot_Movimiento
,Aut_Ordena
,Num_Expdiente
,Del_Especifico
,Sit_Juridica
,Nom_Asociados
,Mpfn_Id
,Inpe_Id)
SELECT
Concat(Pri_Apellido,' ',Seg_Apellido,' ',Nombres),
Dni,
Fec_Ing_Sis,
Fec_Ing_Pen,
Fec_Egr_Pen,
Cod_Penal_Ori,
Des_Penal_Ori,
Cod_Penal_Des
Des_Penal_Des,
Mot_Movimiento,
Aut_Ordena,
Num_Expdiente,
Del_Especifico,
Sit_Juridica,
Nom_Asociados,
Mpfn_Id,
Inpe_Id
FROM dbo.Inpe_Origen
GO
```

Apparently the `SELECT` does not correctly detect all the rows, apart from that in the query they do not indicate any error.

I have tried in different ways but it still appears the same, the tables have a similar structure, but I need to concatenate certain rows

Error:

> Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Comment: It's just a silly typo - in the `SELECT`, you're missing a comma `,` after the column name `Cod_Penal_Des` - therefore, the next column name will be used as the column alias for `Cod_Penal_Des` - instead of as a separate column on its own. With this typo, you have 17 columns in the `INSERT` statement, but only 16 in the `SELECT` to provide the data.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing a comma between Cod_Penal_Des and Des_Penal_Des in your select